# Nash's Axiomatic Bargaining: Source of problems sets and practice questions.

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, game-theory, book-recommendation, nash-equilibrium

From where can I practice questions related to the following topic:

**Nash's Axiomatic Bargaining.**

Any form of book reference or a link to some online problem set would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the recently published book "[Game Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107005485)" by Michael Maschler, Eilon Solan and Shmuel Zamir. It is a very big and comprehensive book which treats many subjects in great detail. One of them is the Nash bargaining model (and more generally "Bargaining Games") in Chapter 15. It has many examples and exercises on it.

---

Note, however, that some topics - such as potential games or Stackelberg equilibria for example (if I am not missing something) - are not treated in this book. But for all the subjects that are treated, the approach of the authors is very explanatory, didactic and supported with many examples. So before you buy it (if so) check the contents to verify that all the subjects that you are interested in, are indeed included in the book. Otherwise it is highly recommended as a textbook for undergraduate and postgraduate level and why not for self-study.

---

**Edit 1**: Some links with online material, [link 1](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEMQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fare.berkeley.edu%2F~antinori%2Fprclass%2FRZ2.pdf&ei=vhJgVL6QL9jZaomIgdAF&usg=AFQjCNFPNv1LkJLqwbRpLMJoT9Mwu_jFvg&bvm=bv.79189006,d.d2s), [link 2](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CFMQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffaculty.georgetown.edu%2Fla2%2FBargaining.pdf&ei=vhJgVL6QL9jZaomIgdAF&usg=AFQjCNErtygGYtCSb2__ySzY_jaLxT80LQ&bvm=bv.79189006,d.d2s), [link 3](http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDoQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fcourses%2Felectrical-engineering-and-computer-science%2F6-254-game-theory-with-engineering-applications-spring-2010%2Flecture-notes%2FMIT6_254S10_lec14.pdf&ei=vhJgVL6QL9jZaomIgdAF&usg=AFQjCNEKITuYmISeGIl1d2SQFI2YjYDuxw&bvm=bv.79189006,d.d2s).